# How to make an infinite sequence in C++

Tags: c++, boost, c++11

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 so C++11 is mostly OK...
boost is also fine, but I would prefer to avoid other libreries, at least not widley used ones.

I want to create a forward only iterator that returns an infinite sequence, in the most elegant way possible. For example a sequence of all the natural numbers.

Basically I want the C++ equivilent of this f# code:

```
let nums =
    seq { while true do
            yield 1
            yield 2
        }
```

the above code basically creates an enumerator that returns [1;2;1;2...]

I know I could do this by writing a class, but there's got to be a shorter way with all the new lambdas and all...

Comment: I suppose if you *really* don't want to write a class then you could use `boost::transform_iterator` applied to `boost::counting_iterator<unsigned>`. Lambdas provide anonymous functor types, they don't provide anonymous iterator types. So on their own they can't be used to define an iterator.

Comment: [Boost Coroutine](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/coroutine/doc/html/index.html) allows you writing code in the style of your f# sample.

Comment: Just a warning: C++ doesn't take well to infinity. It's inherently eager and strictly evaluated, which means you need to go out of your way to make it work nicely.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simpler thing, if you can depend on boost is to write something like this:

```
int i = 0;
auto gen = boost::make_generator_iterator([=]() mutable { return i++; });
```

C++14 version:

```
auto gen = boost::make_generator_iterator([i=0]() mutable { return i++;});
```

Documentation is [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/utility/generator_iterator.htm).

P.S.: I'm not sure if it will work without `result_type` member, which C++03 functor would need.

Comment: Sometimes it helps :)

Comment: But the lambdas need to be mutable because it isn't possible to modify variables captured by value inside non-mutable lambdas.

Comment: True when capturing by value. @MohammedSafwat. As it is this case.

Answer (score 5):

Is this what you want:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() 
{
    auto nums = []
    {
        static unsigned x = 2;
        return ( x++ % 2 ) + 1;
    };

    std::vector< int > v{ nums(), nums(), nums(), nums(), nums() };
    for( auto i : v )
    {
        std::cout << i;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

or I have misunderstood the question?

Comment: that's the general direction, but I want something that poses as a collection, that I could give to the STL.

Comment: @AK_: there are few standard algorithms that make sense when passed an infinite repeating sequence. Which in particular are you planning to use?

Comment: @AK_ - what you mean by "to give to the STL"?

Comment: @KirilKirov: BTW, you don't have to write `[]() -> int { ... }`. Just `[] {...}` would be enough in this case!

Comment: @AK_ - creating a `std::map` and using it for `std::transform` are pretty different - for STL container, you can use it in the initialization (as the lambda returns actual values), while `std::transform` _requires_ input iterator (something, that can be dereferenced and incremented) (see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform _second version_)

Comment: @AK_: you can't create a map directly from an infinite sequence, because you can't have an infinite map. You could use `transform` provided that the output iterator is something that "consumes" the data, for example by printing it. But the only way out of `transform` would be by an exception. Basically, infinite ranges are not a great fit for standard algorithms, except `copy_n` :-) C++ algorithms aren't as nice as coroutines in this respect, they're harder to chain together.

Comment: @AK_: if by "map" you mean `std::map` then I assure you, it cannot be infinite :-) If you mean something lazily-evaluated of your own invention then you might be in business.

Comment: @AK_ - see my edit. You can't have an infinite container, as you don't have infinite memory on your PC, but it's still something.. About `std::transform` - it will be different there, because of the requirement for iterator. Than you can't avoid creating a custom one or using some existing (like boost's for example)

Comment: @SteveJessop of course you can't have an infinite map. But you can use two sequences one finite and one infinite , and just stop when the finite one runs out...

Comment: @KirilKirov I don't want a container. I want an infinite iterator.

Comment: @Jarod42 - no, it's not unspecified, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20266153/stdinitializer-list-and-order-of-evaluation-of-the-elements

Answer (score 3):

I've written a library called [Pipeline](http://snawaz.github.io/foam/pipeline.html) using which you can write such things easily, as:

```
auto infinite_seq = generate(1, [](int i) { return (i % 2) + 1; });
```

Now `infinite_seq` is a *deferred-range* which means it will *generate* the values and give you *when* you ask for it. If you ask for `10` values, it will generate exactly `10` values — this can be expressed as:

```
auto values = infinite_seq | take(10);
```

Or you can write this:

```
auto values = generate(1, [](int i) { return (i % 2) + 1; }) | take(10);

for(auto i : values) 
      //working with i
```

Have a look at the documentation of [generate](http://snawaz.github.io/foam/pipeline/generate.html).

Comment: 1. Again, I prefer to avoid libraries that are not adopted by a large community. 2. I don't doubt your knowledge of C++ , but you make a lot of assertions about LINQ which are GROSSLY incorrect.

Comment: @AK_: No problem. I don't claim it to be perfect either. Hope you get *perfect* solution. As for LINQ, it is just an inspiration, my library is NOT same and identical to LINQ.

Comment: ...  I would like to know *why* you think LINQ is "*GROSSLY incorrect*"?

Comment: 1. your source code looks quite nice. 2. I would further suggest you would take a look at the examples in the RX-CPP library, they have some interesting ideas, not sure if all are good though. 3. I've sent you an EMail explaining what i didn't like about your comparison with linq.

Comment: Is tuis really infinite?  After `2^31-1` the `int` rolls over, and `%` behaves interesimgly on negative `int`, plus the entire overflow undefined issue...  My infinity includes 5 billion.

Comment: So the input is the last iteration's output?  Not the index?

Comment: @Yakk: Yes. :-) ... So the value of `i` is either `1` or `2`. Index-based approach would fail to produce infinite sequence, which is why it is avoided.

Comment: I also assume `for( auto i : generate(1, [](int i) { return (i % 2) + 1; }) )` works?    ... expression seems neat, but I'd be tempted to make member pointers into expression modifiers.  So `expression<Foo> foo; auto age = member(&Foo::age); auto get_age = foo^age;` rather than `auto get_age = age;` -- so the `expression<>` always being the input.  Would mimic LINQ and lambda and non-`expression` syntax in what I think is a good way...

Comment: @Yakk: Yes, that `for` loop would work and it is an infinite loop. And I think you've typo here : *"... `auto get_age = foo^age;` rather than `auto get_age = age;`"* . So I couldn't understand the rest of the comment. Could you rephrase it?

Comment: @Nawaz No typo? `_m(&Foo::age)` in `expression` says "I expect 1 input that is a `Foo` and return the member field `age`". I'm saying that a member accessor that can be attached to an `expression` via `operator^` to extract the `age` field might make for more natural code. So instead of `auto extract_age = memexp(&person::get_age)` we have `expression<person> Person; auto age = memacces(&person::get_age); auto extract_age = Person^age;`, where `extract_age` does the same thing in both cases. `memaccess` doesn't produce an expression, but an expression mutator. Just to get `p.age`-like syntax.

Comment: @Yakk: That could be an alternative syntax. But I don't see any advantage (you're typing more on the contrary). `memexp` is just like `std::mem_fn`, and addtionally it also supports expression syntax; e.g `extract_age * 10` would produce a functor which will return `10` times of age. Anyway, if you're thinking of alternative syntax, then why not `auto extract_age = Person->age` instead, which looks more intuitive.

Comment: @Nawaz Because `->` is a unary operator, not a binary one.

Comment: @Yakk: Still can be supported, using proxy object!

Answer (score 2):

Standard C++ has no real iterator generators which help you avoid writing the class manually. You can take a look at my [`range` library](https://github.com/klmr/cpp11-range) for such an iterator generator to get going. This code essentially allows you to write

```
for (auto i : range(1))
    …
```

which generates the infinite sequence 1, 2, 3, …. [Boost.Iterator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/iterator/doc/) contains tools for transforming one iterator output into another, related output. You could use that to repeatedly cycle over elements from a two-item container (containing the elements `1` and `2`, in your case).

Comment: I've only briefly scanned your library code, but firstly doesn't it need to be `range(1U)` to avoid UB on overflow? Secondly does your `infinite_range_proxy` class support `boost::adaptors::transform(range(0U), [](unsigned i) { return (i % 2) + 1;})`? I think it does because it has `begin()` and `end()`, but if it needs anything else then it should add that :-)

Comment: +1. Your librery looks good, but I won't use it. I don't have the knowladge to review it...

Comment: @SteveJessop I simply wouldn’t let it overflow … ;-) Normally you use infinite sequences as a start and then truncate them later. Secondly, I haven’t actually looked at interoperability with Boost.Iterator at all due to lack of time. I’d love to do that at some point though.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a hammer in your hand, everything around looks like a nail. Lambdas and other C++11 features are sure cool, but you should choose valid tools for problems. In this case I see nothing simpler and more elegant than short class with overloaded operators:

```
class MyInfiniteIter
{
private:
    unsigned int i;

public:
    MyInfiniteIter()
    {
        i = 0;
    }

    int operator *() {

        return i;
    }

    int operator++ () {

        i++;
        if (i == 10)
            i = 0;

        return i;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    for (MyInfiniteIter i;; ++i)
    {
        printf("%d\n", *i);
    }
}
```

Comment: `I know I could do this by writing a class, but there's got to be a shorter way with all the new lambdas and all...`

Comment: `new lambdas and all` doesn't seem to be a good choice here. Their pure existence does not justify using them anywhere, and in this particular case - in my opinion - simple class is the most elegant solution.

Comment: Agreed (in general), but the OP doesn't want classes for some reason. Could be even educational purpose, no idea.

Comment: I think more to the point, this class *is not an iterator*. You must either specialize `iterator_traits` or include the typedefs that you get by inheriting from `std::iterator`.

Comment: Sure, but lambda is no iterator *even more* :)

Comment: @Spook Look at the F# example, look at your class (which entails an extra file BTW), which is more elegant?

Comment: Comparing C++ to C# is like comparing apples to pineapples. C++ is way lower-level and some things are not as simple to be done as in C#. I still say, that *as for C++* this is the most elegant solution. Otherwise you always can implement it in F# and create some kind of wrapper to C++ - you'll get your #-style elegant solution...

Comment: C++ is definitely more "challenging" than C#, but regardless my example was from F#. C++ supports a LOT of functional style programming, and I don't see any reason why I should write a lot of boiler-tape pointless code, when I can achieve what I want with three lines. also C++ doesnt agree with you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20265815/182360

Comment: And so what? Firstly, that boost:: stuff for sure returns you a class instance. Secondly, it could have used function pointer instead of lambda as well. Thirdly, these are external libraries *not* being a part of standard C++ library (quite popular though). How does it fit your problem description?

Answer (score 0):

Here is C++14 [index_sequence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence) comes  helping:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

namespace std
{
   template< int ...i> struct index_sequence{};

   template< int N, int ...i>
   struct make_seq_impl : make_seq_impl< N-1, N-1,i...> {};
   template< int ...i>
   struct make_seq_impl<0,i...>{ typedef index_sequence<i...> type; };

   template< int N > 
   using make_index_sequence  = typename make_seq_impl<N>::type;

} // namespace std


typedef std::vector<int>  integer_list;

template< typename F, int ...i >
integer_list make_periodic_list_impl(F f, std::index_sequence<i...> ) 
 {     
        //      {  1 2 1 2 1 2... }
        return {  f(i) ... };
 }

template< int N , typename F>
integer_list make_periodic_list(F f) 
{
   return make_periodic_list_impl(f, std::make_index_sequence<N>{} );
}



 int main()
 {
   std::vector<int> v = make_periodic_list<20>([](int i){return 1 + (i&1);}); 

     for( auto e : v ) std::cout << e << ' ';
 }
```