# std::initializer_list and order of evaluation of the elements

Tags: c++, c++11, initializer-list, sequence-points

Is the comma (`,`) a sequence point in `std::initializer_list`?

---

example: is this UB or not:

```
#include <vector>

int main() 
{
    auto nums = []
    {
        static unsigned x = 2;
        return ( x++ % 2 ) + 1;
    };

    std::vector< int > v{ nums(), nums(), nums(), nums(), nums() };
    // not sure if this is different: (note the additional brackets)
    // std::vector< int > v({ nums(), nums(), nums(), nums(), nums() });
    for( auto i : v )
    {
        std::cout << i;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There are no "sequence points" any more in C++11. However, the order of evaluation is guaranteed and it is indeed ordered, but I'll search for a duplicate first before answering.

Comment: @DyP - thanks. I didn't find duplicate, although I'm pretty sure I've seen similar question.. I'm almost sure, the order is guaranteed, but not 100%.

Comment: [dcl.init.list]/4 "That is, every value computation and
side effect associated with a given *initializer-clause* is sequenced before every value computation and side
effect associated with any *initializer-clause* that follows it in the comma-separated list of the *initializer-list*."

Comment: @DyP - "There are no "sequence points" " - seriously? That's interesting.. Thanks for the quote - if you add it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @Kiril: Yeah, it's a notion of "sequenced-before" and "sequenced-after", now.

Comment: It's high time for me to take a deeper look at the new standard, obviously. This sounds like a dramatic change to me.

Comment: Possible duplicates, for example: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14442894/420683 http://stackoverflow.com/q/20186084/420683 You'd need to search for *list-initialization* (not `std::initializer_list`), because that's where the order is defined.

Comment: @DyP - I searched, but everything I saw was about the constructor initialization list. The questions is a bit different, I think (variadic templates and this case here), but I'm not 100% positive.

Comment: Also search for the [c++11] tag ;) To answer the question in the code comment: No, it's not different. It's list-initialization in both cases, so the same rules apply wrt sequencing. The second one *could* have a different meaning (in a general case), but is has the same meaning here: Call the `initializer_list` constructor of `vector` with an `initializer_list` constructed via list-initialization.

Comment: Also note `std::generate_n`, it's a bit more programatical then just copying and pasting `num()` `n` times.http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/generate_n

Comment: @111111 - yes, yes, this was just an example for the (obviously outdated) "sequence points".

Comment: @KirilKirov okay. Just making sure; it's an interesting question non the less.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to C++11 § 8.5.4 [dcl.init.list] paragraph 4:

> 4 Within the initializer-list of a braced-init-list, the
>   initializer-clauses, including any that result from pack expansions
>   (14.5.3), are evaluated in the order in which they appear. That is,
>   every value computation and side effect associated with a given
>   initializer-clause is sequenced before every value computation and
>   side effect associated with any initializer-clause that follows it in
>   the comma-separated list of the initializer-list.

As far as I know GCC 4.8.1 has a bug relative to evaluation of initializers. I described it here

http://cpp.forum24.ru/?1-3-0-00000063-000-0-0-1378892425

Though the text is written in Russion but it can be simply translated in English by using for example google translate.