# Apply function on each element in parameter pack

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming, variadic-templates

I have the following template function with specialization:

```
// Pass the argument through ...
template<typename T, typename U=T>
U convert(T&& t) {
  return std::forward<T>(t);
}

// ... but convert std::strings
const char* convert(std::string s) {
  return s.c_str();
}
```

If I then have a variadic template function like:

```
template<typename ... Args>
void doSomething(Args ... args) {
  // Convert parameter pack using convert function above
  // and call any other variadic templated function with
  // the converted args.
}
```

Is there any way to convert the parameter pack using the convert function as in the comment?

My original goal was being to be able to pass std::string to '%s' in a printf like function without having to manually calling .c_str() on the strings first. But I am also interested in general if this can be done in a simple way, my tries so far failed.

Comment: btw, your `doSomething` doesn't accept forwarding references, while `convert` implies it should. Also `convert(std::string)` returns a dangling pointer. So you may want to do some changes.

Comment: @StoryTeller if I as suggested just want to print it I assume it's ok with the pointer since I do not plan to keep it around?

Comment: `s` is local to convert. How can it be ok?

Comment: @StoryTeller ok I see the string is taken by value, I can use a reference instead.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
template<typename ... Args>
void doSomething(Args ... args) {
  something(convert(args)...);
}
```

Where `something(convert(args)...)` is a [parameter pack expansion](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack) that expands to:

```
// pseudocode
something(convert(arg0), convert(arg1), convert(arg2), ...)
```

---

BTW, you might want to take `args` by *forwarding references* in order to avoid unnecessary copies and to properly propagate *lvalue references*:

```
template<typename... Args>
void doSomething(Args&& ... args) {
  something(convert(std::forward<Args>(args))...);
}
```

Comment: I think it's worth noting that `something(convert(arg0), convert(arg1), convert(arg2), ...)` is not guarranteed to execute convert() in order from left-to-right. I think using initalizer-lists instead would force left-to-right execution: [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20266153/stdinitializer-list-and-order-of-evaluation-of-the-elements)